# Filter a query in Prisma with results

Tags: mongodb, backend, nodes, prisma

I am trying to find a way that with PRISMA I could filter a query with the query results...
Something like this:

```
prisma.card.findMany({
    include: {
      user: true,
      project: true,
      transaction: {
        where: {
          date_created: {
            lte: getInterval(card.interval),
            gte: getInterval(card.interval),
          },
        },
      },
      snapshots: true,
    },
})
```

Basically I am querying cards and including transactions, then I have a function to get an interval, but I will need the prop from the card (interval) to be used in the function.

The way bellow is not working, just an example.

Do you know if is there any other way? I am using Mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `include` with `select` to be able to apply filters to a relation when you are searching for something in Prisma.

Docs: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#filter-a-list-of-relations

Your query will look something like this:

```
prisma.card.findMany({
    // include => select, make sure to select any other fields you need here too
    select: {
      user: true,
      project: true,
      transaction: {
        where: {
          date_created: {
            lte: getInterval(card.interval),
            gte: getInterval(card.interval),
          },
        },
      },
      snapshots: true,
    },
})
```

Your TypeScript types should also be able to guide you on what types are available on the `transaction` property and what's not. The emitted Prisma Client is REALLY helpful in that regard!

Comment: Hello friend, thank you so much for your reply, but I am still getting errors: 
Cannot find name 'card'.ts(2304) Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you're referencing a variable that doesn't exist (`card`) - How do you define the `card` variable? It was in your original code so it's coming from somewhere

Comment: Well, I need to send the card.interval from Prisma query findMany that I am doing there... So, basically, I need that information to filter the transactions in order to know what interval from transactions that I will send

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean. You are referencing the `card` variable before it is defined. You need to resolve that error in order to resolve the error in your first comment. If `card` is a single card, it has to come from somewhere. If it is the output of the `prisma.card.findMany`, you need to get that data some other way